# .lib is not a valid Win32 application - Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, lib

I am trying to create a simple .lib file in C++ to try and use the code in my C# using C++/CLI wrapping techniques. The problem is, my C++ code in itself isn't compiling successfully. It keeps pushing the 'not a valid Win32 application' error. I tried looking up the same problem and many answers suggested there were .NET framework issues with Windows XP. But I am running it on 'Visual Studio 2015 (v140)' Platform Toolset. My Desktop is a 64bit OS (x64 processor)running Windows 10 pro.

Here's a snippet of my Project Properties:

[image: Below is my header file code:]

```
 #pragma once

 namespace AddTwoNumbersLib
 {
    class AddClass
    {
        public:
        static double Add(double x, double y);
    };
}
```

And this is my .cpp code :

```
     #include "AddClass.h"

     namespace AddTwoNumbersLib
 {
        double AddClass::Add(double x, double y)
         {
              return x + y;
        }
}
```

I'm struggling with this since I'm an amateur. Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did the build fail? You didn't try to accidentally run it right? Could you add the entire build message to your post?

Comment: While the error pops up. I get a 'Build succeeded' message on the bottom left.

Comment: Your build has succeeded, and you have the .lib file. You tried to run it I think by the "play" button. Just Right-click on the project, click Build. You should be good to go!

Comment: It works! Thank you!

Comment: @StutiRastogi - ...and what do I do after I Build? (the Build was ok)

Answer (score 9):

I'm guessing it builds correctly but you're trying to run the .lib like an application.  Right click on the project and select 'Build'

Comment: I BUILT with right click. The Build was ok... and what do I do after that?

Comment: @Migrate2Lazarusseemyprofile if the static library is a part of the solution mark it as start project